# React call data from Json

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, components, react-component

Sorry, I'm new to coding, i have some error when i doing my project, 
the component structure is: profile > boxes > box

1) why "TypeError: props.total is undefined", i want to show the data in the box component from Json

2) and how to calculate the success rate in jsx? i tried to set a formula in Json.................ya...i know this is stupid

hope someone can help me resolve this problem

thanks a lot!

```js
import React from 'react';
import Box from '../Box';

const Boxes = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="d-flex justify-content-center profile-record">
            <Box className="record-div" id="record-prediction" title={props.total.title} count={props.total.count} />
            <Box className="record-div" id="record-win" title={props.win.title} count={props.win.count} />
            <Box className="record-div" id="record-rate" title={props.successRate.title} count={props.successRate.count} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Boxes;
```

```js
import React from 'react';

const Box = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="record-div" id="record-prediction">
            <h2>{props}</h2>
            <p>{props}</p>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Box;
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import Footer from '../components/Footer';
import Info from '../components/modules/Info';
import './Profile.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { Users } from '../Users';
import Boxes from '../components/modules/Boxes';

class Profile extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="content">
                <header className="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <h1>Profile</h1>
                </header>
                <Info key={Users.id} name = {Users[1].name} pic = {Users[1].pic} status = { Users[1].status}/>
                <Boxes key={Users.id} title = {Users[1].total.title} count={Users[1].total.count} />
                <Footer className="footer"/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Profile;
```

```js
export const Users = [{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Perry",
    "status": "ddddddd",
    "total":{
      "title":"Total",
      "count": 10
    }, 
    "win":{
      "title":"Win",
      "count": 8
    },
    "successRate":{
      "title":"Rate",
      "count": "80%"
    },
    "pic": 'https://scontent-hkg3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/526566_10150652683517909_70002103_n.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=7ceaa1ea2ca75ae718a4234ec366d9f9&oe=5C0DEA6B'
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "id": 2,
    "name": "HKJC",
    "status": "delectus aut autemdelectus delectus aut autemdelectusdelectus aut autemdelectusdelectus aut autemdelectusdelectus aut autemdelectusdelectus aut autemdelectusdelectus aut autemdelectus aut autemdelectus aut autemdelectus aut autemdelectus aut autemdelectus aut autemdelectus aut autemdelectus aut autem",
    "total":{
      "title":"Total",
      "count": 10
    }, 
    "win":{
      "title":"Win",
      "count": 8
    },
    "successRate":{
      "title":"Rate",
      "count": "80%"
    },
    "pic": 'https://scontent-hkg3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/526566_10150652683517909_70002103_n.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=7ceaa1ea2ca75ae718a4234ec366d9f9&oe=5C0DEA6B'
  }
]
```

Comment: See [ask]. Generally, only one question per posting, please. Also, this looks a lot like you want us to debug your code, and SO is a TERRIBLE debugger. What have you done to solve this? What research? [Edit] the question and make it clear what you want to do, what you have tried, and what results you get. Also, good reference: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: sorry about that, and i will improve my asking skill, thanks for sharing the reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing your props wrong then trying to get back data from them.

Here:

```
<Boxes key={Users.id} title = {Users[1].total.title} count={Users[1].total.count} />
```

You are passing two props: `title` and `count`. These are coming from `Users[1]`'s `total` prop.

But here:

```
<Box className="record-div" id="record-prediction" title={props.total.title} count={props.total.count} />
```

You are trying to use these props as `props.total.title` and `props.total.count`. There is no `props.total`. You have only `title` and `count`.

You should use it like this:

```
<Box className="record-div" id="record-prediction" title={props.title} count={props.count} />
```

But, instead of passing separately, you can pass `total` directly:

```
<Box className="record-div" id="record-prediction" total={props.total} />
```

Then you can use this:

```
<Box className="record-div" id="record-prediction" title={props.total.title} count={props.total.count} />
```

This is the same as `win`, etc. But, passing props one by one like that is not so wise. You can map the users then pass the related components as `user` maybe. So, you don't struggle too much with props.

One last thing, you can't render props like this:

```
<div className="record-div" id="record-prediction">
    <h2>{props}</h2>
    <p>{props}</p>
</div>
```

`props` are objects and we can't render objects directly to the DOM. Use what you have in the `props` object:

```
<div className="record-div" id="record-prediction">
    <h2>{props.title}</h2>
    <p>{props.count}</p>
</div
```

I don't understand the second question. What do you want to calculate and where do you want to do that? When asking questions try to be as specific as possible.

Comment: thanks a lots, you like a teacher, i'm still trying your suggestion, there are no error now but did not render the data, i will using your suggest concept to think thanks again